# How to split a specific string after in java

Tags: java, string, split, trim

I have the following string:

```
String result = "@sequence@A:exampleA@B:exampleB";
```

I would like to split this string into two strings like this:

```
String resulta = "sequence";

String resultb = "@A:exampleA@B:exampleB";
```

How can I do this? I'm new to Java programming language.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to skip and remove @ only in first part but 2nd part shall contain @?

Comment: Can you explain the rule(s) you followed to get to your desired result? Or maybe provide some more examples?

Comment: @Optional - yes

Comment: @Felk I just want to split this string into two parts. In the first one I want to express the word without "@" and in the second rest of string. Good? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want typical split, (Specific to your string), you can call substring and get the part of it like below:

```
     String s = "@sequence@A:exampleA@B:exampleB";
        String s1= s.substring(1,s.indexOf("@",1));
        System.out.println(s1);
        String s2= s.substring(s1.length()+1);
        System.out.println(s2);
     }
```

> Edit as per your comment

```
String s3= s.substring(s.indexOf("@",1));
System.out.println(s3);
```

Comment: Thanks very much :) But can you get "s2" only with main "s" variables?

Comment: @Kima321 Edited answer as per your comment using only s. In s1, we are doing substring till 2nd @. In s3, we are doing substring "from" 2nd @

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = "@sequence@A:exampleA@B:exampleB";

if(result.indexOf("@") == 0)
    result = result.substring(1, result.length());

String resultA = result.substring(0, result.indexOf("@"));
String resultB = result.substring(resultA.length(), result.length());
```

Comment: this will not give the op the 2nd string with @.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
    String result = "@sequence@A:exampleA@B:exampleB", resulta, resultb;
    int splitPoint = result.indexOf('@',1);
    resulta = result.substring(1, splitPoint);
    resultb = result.substring(splitPoint);

    System.out.println(resulta+", "+resultb);
```